# Dojo data attribute finding and Dojo equivalent to jQuery's $(this)

Tags: jquery, dojo, innerhtml, custom-data-attribute

Hey all I am trying to get the value from one of my elements. The data element is called `data-lang` and here is an example of it:

```
<p class="mainText" data-lang="es">Welcome</p>
```

This is currently my Dojo javascript:

```
dojo.query("[data-lang]").forEach(
      function(item){
         var theText = dojo.attr(item, "innerHTML");
      }
);
```

This doesn't seem to work as I don't get anything. What I am looking to get from the above is `"es"`

Also, how does Dojo handle the jQuery equivalent of `$(this)`?

Answer (score 1):

The query above should work fine. Are you sure you're waiting for the DOM to be ready? If you're using AMD, you should use the following:

```
require([ "dojo/query", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(query) {
  // Code
});
```

Or the following for non-AMD:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
  // Code
});
```

---

About your second question, there is no alternative. The `dojo/query` does not pass the current node as scope of the callback functions like the one you're using in the `forEach()`.

However, you can usually get the current node as a parameter, so you can do the following:

```
dojo.query("[data-lang]").forEach(function(item) {
  query(item).attr("innerHTML");
});
```

But remember that the result will be an array if you use the `dojo/query` module.

Here's a full example: http://jsfiddle.net/5nguxm8f/